# How to paginate api platform results on Item Operations?

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, api-platform.com

Hey guys I have a little problem with api platform, i have a "GET" item operation with a custom controller, and it fetch about 5000 result, so what i want to do is to limit results to 500 per page, any one could help me please ?

I already tried 'paginationItemsPerPage' and 'paginationMaximumItemsPerPage' but it works only on collection operations ?

Thanks

Comment: This is really dependent on the api itself. You should message them and ask if there is a way to limit the items

Comment: Thanks i'll ask them :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you use a custom Controller, may you use a custom repository function also, then you have to check your respository function hast the psoiblity to set a limit and an offset.